# extern must have access to class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor, extern

There are many ways to access class members as you all know, my problem now is. if the class constructor/deconstructor if public, the 'new' usage is allowed and also 'extern', if it is private, i can make 'GetInstance' only class which wouldn't allow 'new' usage, which is good for class that should have 1 pointing instance to them only (such as a server which counts current logged in users), and 'new' is good for classe that point to many objects (such as a class that points to a new objects, for example a new player logged int, it would create a new pointer to each on of them ), and a map would store a pointer to a 'new' of that object. The problem is, shouldnt 'extern' be allowed to access from a global object private constructors? since 'new' usage isnt allowed? Take a look at the example below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


//CMover.h-------------------------------------
#define MAX_MOVER_NAME 32

class CMover
{
private:
    BOOL m_bInitialized;
    BOOL m_bIsWalking;
    unsigned m_uMetersPercused;
    TCHAR m_szName[MAX_MOVER_NAME+1];

    //CMover( LPCTSTR szMoverName, BOOL bInitialized = TRUE, BOOL bWalking = TRUE, unsigned uMeters = 0 );

public:
        CMover() { };
    virtual ~CMover(){};
};
//---------------------------------------------



//CMover.cpp---------------
CMover g_Mover; //CMover was created in order to have many 'new' usage, so each 'new' object points to a new player
// Making a global object of it is a big failure
//---------------------------


//CServer.h---------------
class CConnectedUsers
{
private:
    CConnectedUsers() {}; //ok, new cannot access, this class should be used as 1 object only
    virtual ~CConnectedUsers() {}; //to count up connected users, 'new' should never be used
public:
    map<u_long,CMover*>m_UserMng;

    //I Could use GetInstance, that any pointers craeted (CConnectedUsers *pCUser = CConnectedUsers::GetInstance() ) would
    //point to it
    static CConnectedUsers* GetInstance( void )
    {
            static CConnectedUsers mObj;
            return &mObj;
    }
};
//------------------------

//CServer.cpp ------
//Or in this case i would like to make a global object, so on CWhatever.cpp that included CServer.h i could use
//(extern CConnectedUsers g_Users;) which is also 1 object-only so no GetInstance would be needed and I would use
//(g_Users.m_UserMng...) directly after external declared
//PROBLEM is, making constructor private regulates the class to be 1 object only, but it doesn't allow external usage
//why is that???
CConnectedUsers g_Users;
//-----------------

//Main.cpp ...etcc

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    CMover *pMover = new CMover;
    cout << pMover << endl << &pMover << endl; //points to a new object, pointer stored in a region

    CMover *pMov2 = new CMover;
    cout << pMov2 << endl << &pMov2 << endl << endl; //points to a new object, pointer stored in another region

    CConnectedUsers *pCUser = CConnectedUsers::GetInstance();
    CConnectedUsers *pCUser2 = CConnectedUsers::GetInstance();
    cout << pCUser << endl << &pCUser << endl; //points to CConnectedUsers, pointer stored in a region
        cout << pCUser2 << endl << &pCUser2 << endl; //points to same CConnectedUsers, pointer stored in another region

    //also another question is, do I need to check these pointers integrity by doing:
            if( pCUser )
            {
                //??
            }

    system("pause>nul");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't `extern`.  A declaration with `extern` doesn't create an object, and doesn't need access to a constructor.

However, an `extern` reference has to find an object defined somewhere, and the one definition (not merely declaration) doesn't have access to the constructor, since it's a namespace member, not a class member.

This is completely expected and consistent.  Expressions evaluated at namespace scope are outside the class and therefore have no special privilege wrt private members.

You can instead use a "lock-and-key" system to make a public constructor unusable from any other file.  For example:

```
// header file
class Once
{
public:
    struct Forward;
    Once(Forward);
};

extern Once g_singleton;

// implementation file
#include "Once"
namespace { struct Local {}; }
struct Once::Forward : Local {};

Once g_singleton(Once::Forward());
```

It is impossible to instantiate the class from any other compilation unit, since no other compilation unit has the definition of `Once::Forward`, which must be passed by value to the constructor.  And any attempt to define `Once::Forward` in any other compilation unit will be an ODR violation.

Comment: Oh yes, you are very right, my conception of it was wrong, i was so focused on using it on my other file it didn't even came up i was trying to create an object without privileges. Any ideas of how could I use 'external' that way?

Comment: Oh i see, wasn't of my habit to use namespace, I'll look forward to it. Thanks ^^

Comment: Hey, also please answer if i have to check the pointer integrity when using 'getinstance' method.

Comment: @ViniciusHorta: The address of a variable will always be non-NULL.  Only pointers returned from factory functions (such as `malloc`) or explicitly set to NULL can sometimes be NULL.

Comment: should the compiler warn you if `Once::Forward` is defined more than once?

Comment: @diffeomorphism: It's a type, so you can't define it more than once in the same compilation unit, but you can have it defined in every compilation unit without causing any "multiple definition" linker error.  For auto-generated functions like the copy constructor, the compiler will work together with the linker to automatically pick one definition.  My answer gives instructions for only defining it in one compilation unit.  Declarations, unlike definitions, can be repeated as many times as you like with no ill effects.